# Basic Bar Chart with plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I try to do a bar charts, with this code

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Bar(
            x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y=[20, 14, 23]
    )]

py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

But I got this error :

> ```
> PlotlyLocalCredentialsError               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-42-9eae40f28f37> in <module>()
>       3             y=[20, 14, 23]
>       4     )]
> ----> 5 py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py
> ```
>
> in iplot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
>           149     if 'auto_open' not in plot_options:
>           150         plot_options['auto_open'] = False
>       --> 151     url = plot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
>           152 
>           153     if isinstance(figure_or_data, dict):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py
> ```
>
> in plot(figure_or_data, validate, **plot_options)
>           239 
>           240     plot_options = _plot_option_logic(plot_options)
>       --> 241     res = _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
>           242     if res['error'] == '':
>           243         if plot_options['auto_open']:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py
> ```
>
> in _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
>          1401                       cls=utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
>          1402     credentials = get_credentials()
>       -> 1403     validate_credentials(credentials)
>          1404     username = credentials['username']
>          1405     api_key = credentials['api_key']
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py
> ```
>
> in validate_credentials(credentials)
>          1350     api_key = credentials.get('api_key')
>          1351     if not username or not api_key:
>       -> 1352         raise exceptions.PlotlyLocalCredentialsError()
>          1353 
>          1354
>
> ```
> PlotlyLocalCredentialsError: 
> Couldn't find a 'username', 'api-key' pair for you on your local machine. To sign in temporarily (until you stop running Python), run:
> >>> import plotly.plotly as py
> >>> py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')
>
> Even better, save your credentials permanently using the 'tools' module:
> >>> import plotly.tools as tls
> >>> tls.set_credentials_file(username='username', api_key='api-key')
>
> For more help, see https://plot.ly/python.
> ```

Any idea to help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the traceback in the error. In this case, it's even more helpful than usual. The solution is given to you here:

```
PlotlyLocalCredentialsError: 
Couldn't find a 'username', 'api-key' pair for you on your local machine. To sign in temporarily (until you stop running Python), run:
>>> import plotly.plotly as py
>>> py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')

Even better, save your credentials permanently using the 'tools' module:
>>> import plotly.tools as tls
>>> tls.set_credentials_file(username='username', api_key='api-key')

For more help, see https://plot.ly/python.
```

So, enter your credentials used when you signed up to the site before you attempt to make a plot. You may have to sign in in a web browser and request for an API key to be generated, it is not the same as your password.